# Why does the variable outside main import no problem but the one inside does not?

Tags: python, function, import, program-entry-point

I have simplified this to isolate my question.

I need to import a variable that is inside the def main(): bit, but as I've demonstrated here, I can't. Why does the variable outside main import no problem but the one inside does not?

#script 1

```
x=('this is outside the main script')

def main():
y=('this is inside the main script')

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

#script2

```
from script1 import *
print(x)
print(y)
```

executing script2:

this is outside the main script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/harvey/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/script2.py", line 4, in <module>
print(y)
NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see the variable outside the main imports but the variable inside does not.

Any help is appreciated!!

Here are screen grabs if you wish instead!
[script 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woU7f.png)
[script 2 with execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipOTd.png)

Comment: Why would you want to be able to import local variables? The whole point of scope is to hide them.

Comment: `x` is a module attribute (or a module global variable); `y` is a *local* variable inside a function; it's not part of the module in anyway.

Comment: Because, `y` defined in `main()` function and not visible out of function's scope.

Comment: You may be thinking that the function named `main()` has special status as it does in other languages. In Python it has no special status and is called `main()` only by convention.  So variables local to `main()` are just as hidden as variables local to other functions.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I see, is there a way to get a value I obtained inside the scope, outside the scope?

Answer (score 0):

`x` is defined in the scope of your first script. But, `y` only exists in the scope of the `main()` function in that script. Indeed, if you tried to access `y` in script 1 outside of the `main()` function, it would give you the same error! If you want to access `y` like this, it needs to be defined outside of `main()`.